# jQuery If android load css

Tags: jquery, android, media-queries

how can load and apply css if detects android:

```
if( navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i) {
load css ..
}
else {
dont load css ..
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("head").append("<style ...");
```

Is your phone in landscape orientation? This media query executes only if you are in landscape.